# Who uses Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to understand the adoption of SalesforceDX within the enterprise customer base. Has anyone (not ISV) adopted Salesforce DX to a significant extend (not counting experiment) ?

Comment: I'm currently working on a project where we use SFDX for all development.

Comment: cool. are you an ISV and how big is the project ?

Comment: My company is an ISV, but the project is not a managed package, it's a custom implementation specifically for a client. The client is a company with around 200 employees, the project we're working on will be rolled out company wide. We act as an implementation partner for at least the first 6 months of the project, after which we either continue our service or the work is taken over by internal employees.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous roles (at an enterprise end-user) I built two in-house applications with Salesforce DX. Both were ideal use cases for SFDX to have a nil adoption cost: fresh development of fairly well-isolated pieces of functionality.

It is a powerful tool with many different applications. It's true that the time cost of converting an existing large-scale codebase to SFDX can be high, but - particularly for newer development or for building applications that are more self-contained relative to the remainder of a company's org - there are many ways to apply SFDX for non-ISVs without incurring substantial transition costs from whatever form the existing development infrastructure takes.

Comment: I don't disagree with using it for smaller, self-contained app. Reality is most enterprise have a Quote to Cash implementation of Salesforce that has a very messy dependency graph. I've worked with a dozen of team who do CI/CD extremely well simply with Metadata API & GIT without DX. How much time and cost do you think it would take to decompose this happy soup + on going effort require to manage dependencies/ DI injection ? And the value you gain in comparison to these effort ?

It seems to me that the happy soup is indeed happy.

Comment: There isn't a generalized answer to that. The cost will vary wildly from org to org, as will the benefit. Orgs that care a lot about automated testing are more likely to make the investment.